# Oscurart Tools installation

Tags: add-on, installation

I am running Blender 2.75. I installed [Oscurart Tools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Oscurart_Tools) and simply can't find the tool. I enabled it in User Preferences, but I don't see the panel on the left hand side of the screen.

Can someone assist me with this? I am fairly new to blender and not all up on where some tools can be found. I have tried to search on here for Oscurart Tools and I have come up with nothing.

Comment: Which version of the tools?, I have 3.2.

Comment: I have 3.1 I just got it today. Wonder why I have one version back

Comment: I got it from here http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Oscurart_Tools

Comment: I'm wondering if you have 2 versions of oscurart tools, as they are in the 2.75 distro.  The user prefs Addons window usually has warning messages if this is the case, or press F8 to reload addons and have a look at the console. (system not python) My suggestion is remove the one you installed from link above, by deleting the oscurart_tools folder & check and see if you have them already in the addons_contrib folder.

Comment: There was nothing in there when I put the files in there.

Answer (score 3):

Oscurart tools  are included in the  addons_contrib folder with blender distro 2.75, which going by your screenie, is the one you are using.

I'm using 2.76.1 RC and have v3.2 not sure if that's the one with 2.75.

Version 3.2 (and the whole addon_contrib) is here
https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons-contrib.git/tree/HEAD:/oscurart_tools

Notice that you have to enable the "Testing" category to see them in the list.

[image: Install]

They're in the toolbar of the 3Dview, press T in the 3D view, then click the Oscurart tools tab.

[image: Oscurart Tools]

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?294671-Oscurart-Tools-Update-(rig-model-render-setting-amp-more)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. vI don't have that available as you can see by this [screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws9p2.png). I have looked everywhere and I can't find the access to those tools.